# Flutter: I want to apply font on runtime to whole app Text

Tags: flutter

I have language selection settings in my app. On the basis of language selection English or Arabic , I want to use different font family. I did it inside MaterialApp() but it will not achieve my target.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'OnlyTick',  
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
        buttonColor: Colors.indigo,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.indigo),
        accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.indigoAccent),
        fontFamily: appLang == 'English'?'Proxima':'DroidKufi',
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashScreenPage(),
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // const TranslationsDelegate(), //TODO: will create it later, refer https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/internationalization---make-an-flutter-application-multi-lingual/
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''),
        const Locale('ar', ''),
      ],
      // setHome(),
      routes: routes,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you  share the code part where you are changing the `fontFamily` ?

Comment: Please check added code.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're running your project using the following structure:

```
    void main() => runApp(new App());
```

Add the function `setAppFontFamily` to your `App` class which will be responsible for changing you application `fontFamily`:

```
    class App extends StatefulWidget {
      App({Key key,}) :

     super(key: key);

     @override
     _AppState createState() => new _AppState();

      static void setAppFontFamily(BuildContext context, String _selectedFontFamily) {
      _AppState state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<_AppState>();
         state.setState(() {
            state._fontFamily = _selectedFontFamily;
         });
      }


     }
```

After that add a local variable to your `_AppState` class or whatever the name you're currently using for your `State` class;

```
     String _fontFamily = 'Proxima' ; //Initial value before any selection is made
```

Then assign `_fontFamily` to the `fontFamily` property of your Material App `Theme`:

```
     theme: ThemeData(
     primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
     buttonColor: Colors.indigo,
     iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.indigo),
     accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.indigoAccent),
     fontFamily: _fontFamily,
     ),
```

After doing all these steps, you'll be able to change the `fontFamily` of your app from anywhere in your application using the below line:

```
     App.setAppFontFamily(context, 'DroidKufi');
```

Comment: Where I have to call `App.setAppFontFamily(context, 'fontname');`

Comment: Can you explain to me how to set font from another screen? where can I write this like?

Comment: @PratikButani you can call from drop down where the user can click on different fonts to change the text font

Answer (score 4):

**Declare the font in the `pubspec.yaml`**

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

**Set a font as the default**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Custom Fonts',
      // Set Raleway as the default app font.
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

For more reference [Flutter Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts)

Answer (score 0):

Set the Theme using the MaterialApp's builder callback:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, navigator) {
        String appLang = Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode;

        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
          buttonColor: Colors.indigo,
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.indigo),
          accentIconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.indigoAccent),
          textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
                fontFamily: appLang == 'en' ? 'Proxima' : 'DroidKufi',
              ),
          ),
          child: navigator as Widget,
        );
      },
```

For details, see this article: https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-different-fonts-for-different-locales-d190a89b58c