# Set font features for theme font in Flutter

Tags: flutter, fonts, themes

In Flutter, you can specify a default font in `ThemeData`:

```
fontFamily: 'Nunito Sans',
```

Is there a way to simply set the `FontFeature` for use in the whole theme, e.g. `FontFeature.enable('salt')` (to enable alternative glyphs from the font)?

I guess I could go through the whole theme setting things like `inputDecorationTheme.hintStyle` etc etc, but that seems like a lot of work!

Answer (score -1):

This code lets you use your fontFamily for all your app text

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        fontFamily: "myFont",//set your font or what ever you want here for your whole app
      textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline: TextStyle(fontSize: 72.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use this for all properties you want to set for your App

For those who wants to change theme features at runtime, please refer [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55085603/8773560)

Comment: That would be a good answer to the question, "how do I set the fontFamily for my app?" However, this question is about how to set font features.

Comment: What do you mean by font features ? fontSize, text color, fontWeight?

Answer (score -1):

How about a real answer that solves the problem, from flutter docs theFontFeaure class:
import 'dart:ui';

// ...

final TextStyle titleStyle = TextStyle(
fontSize: 18,
fontFeatures: const [FontFeature.enable('smcp')],
color: Colors.blueGrey[600],
);

// ...

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// The Cardo, Milonga and Raleway Dots fonts can be downloaded from
// Google Fonts (https://www.google.com/fonts).
return Scaffold(
body: Center(
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
const Spacer(flex: 5),
Text('regular numbers have their place:', style: titleStyle),
const Text('The 1972 cup final was a 1-1 draw.',
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'Cardo',
fontSize: 24,
)),
const Spacer(),
Text('but old-style figures blend well with lower case:',
style: titleStyle),
const Text('The 1972 cup final was a 1-1 draw.',
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'Cardo',
fontSize: 24,
fontFeatures: [FontFeature.oldstyleFigures()])),
const Spacer(),
const Divider(),
const Spacer(),
Text('fractions look better with a custom ligature:',
style: titleStyle),
const Text('Add 1/2 tsp of flour and stir.',
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: 'Milonga',
fontSize: 24,
fontFeatures: [FontFeature.alternativeFractions()])),
const Spacer(),
const Divider(),
const Spacer(),
Text('multiple stylistic sets in one font:', style: titleStyle),
const Text('Raleway Dots',
style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Raleway Dots', fontSize: 48)),
Text('Raleway Dots',
style: TextStyle(
fontFeatures: [FontFeature.stylisticSet(1)],
fontFamily: 'Raleway Dots',
fontSize: 48,
)),
const Spacer(flex: 5),
],
),
),
);
}

To find out what features your font has use this site:

https://wakamaifondue.com/

just drag drop your font file to get the full list of font features

Answer (score -1):

Use this command in terminal
`flutter upgrade`
Sometimes upgrading flutter SDK version to latest, can solve the problem.
OR read the version upgrade in pub dev, of the package causing error.